# Nodejs - taking array object value

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, loops, object

I'm a beginner in nodejs , i want to insert some values to database by calling an api and i have got api result as ,

```
[  { 
"rowId": "0",
"group": "RBEIBAN:SMP",
"zoomLevel": "12", 
"latitude": "12.955081", 
"vehicleLocations":
   [ { 
           "rowId": 0,
           "latitude": "12.955081", 
           "longitude": "77.641369",
           "speed": 0, 
     },
     {
                "rowId": 1,
                "latitude": "12.936186",
                "longitude": "77.611698",
                "speed": 0


    } ]
}]
```

my question is, how can i geI only vehiclelocation from this ? and  how can insert into database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Please spend some time making the question understandable, or even readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes your response is an object and not a string (if string then use JSON.parse(str) first).

Your response is an array of objects, in the example you have given, there is one object in the array. You want response[0].vehicleLocations